# How to sort products in category by post id in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

In shop, some products belong to multiple categories. This makes default WooCommerce ordering not working, because if one product is first in category A then other product can't be first in category B if both belong to the same category.

I want to find a way to sort products in shop categories by post id in particular order I want ( I will supply IDs).

So far I came up with:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'my_ordering_function', 20, 1 );
function my_ordering_function( $args ) {

    $product_category = 'my-category'; 

    if( ! is_product_category($product_category) ) return $args;

    $args['post__in'] = array( 74, 116, 3565, 3563 );
    $args['orderby'] = 'post__in';
    $args['order'] = 'ASC';

    return $args;
}
```

This code should do the job, but after examining [`woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args` source code](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Query.html#499), it looks like post__in is not even supported.

Any ideas on how to dictate my own product order per category?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your approach, you can do this in the parent function of the function that uses the `woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args` filter.

The function you are looking for is `product_query`, in this function you have an action hook `woocommerce_product_query`. For your use case, something like this would work.

```
function my_ordering_function( $q, $this ) {
    $q->set( 'post__in', array( 74, 116, 3565, 3563 ) );
    $q->set( 'orderby', 'post__in' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'my_ordering_function', 10, 2 );
```

**P.S.** This function is also in the same file that you referenced. You can have a look there to see how it works.

Comment: Yes it works, without $this parameter. Very clever idea. Thank you.